# Write into a file a block of lines with couple values at each line until index given

Tags: python, text

I have the following block of lines (83 lines) contained into `data` array of text:

```
UseOmegam_ch 0
UseOmegaDE_ch 1
UseOmegab_ch 0
Usew0_ch 0
Usewa_ch 0
Useh_ch 0
Usens_ch 0
Usesigma8_ch 0
Usegamma_ch 1
Usesp_ch 1
Usesv_ch 1
UseGCspecbias_ch 0
UseGCspecPS_ch 1
UseWLAia_ch 0
UseWLBia_ch 0
UseWLnia_ch 0
UseGCphotbias_ch 0
VFidOmegam 0.32
VFidOmegaDE 0.68
VFidOmegab 0.05
VFidw0 -1
VFidwa 0
VFidh 0.67
VFidns 0.96
VFidsigma8 0.815534
VFidgamma 0.545455
VFidWLAia 1.72
VFidWLBia 2.17
VFidWLnia -0.41
VFidWLCia 0.0134
VFidAs 2.12605
VFidWnu 0.00143717
VStepOmegam 0.001
VStepOmegaDE 0.001
VStepOmegab 0.001
VStepw0 0.001
VStepwa 0.001
VSteph 0.001
VStepns 0.001
VStepsigma8 0.001
VStepgamma 0.001
VStepsp 0.001
VStepsv 0.001
VStepGCspecbias 0.0001
VStepGCspecPS 0.0001
VStepWLAia 0.001
VStepWLBia 0.001
VStepWLnia 0.001
VStepGCphotbias 0.0001
VSteplnDa 0.0001
VSteplnH 0.0001
VSteplnfs8 0.0001
XSAF_ch 0
SpecSAF_ch 0
FNF_ch 0
Camb_ch 1
Cutting_l_V 60
SavePrC_ch 0
UseGC_ch 0
UseWL_ch 0
UseXC_ch 0
VRS_bins 11
Vzmin 0.001
Vzmax 3.731
Vlnum 60
Vlmin_GCWL 10
Vlmax_GC 3000
Vlmax_WL 5000
VSurfArea 15000
VGdensity 30
Vprec_Int_z 100
zcut_ch 1
Vsig_epsilon 0.3
UsePZ_ch 0
Vzrange_0 0.636396
Valpha 1.5
Vphotoz_cb 1
Vphotoz_zb 0
Vphotoz_sigb 0.05
Vphotoz_c0 1
Vphotoz_z0 0.1
Vphotoz_sig0 0.05
Vphotoz_f_out 0.1
```

I am looking for write a sub-block of all these lines (52 first couples) into a file using maximum line index of this block (so index 52 or rather 51 in python notation):

I tried :

```
with open('../QTLauncher/Parameters_W.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write(data[0:52])
```

But this command line stores the first 52 characters, not the first 52 lines.

How could I store the 52 first lines of couples contained in array `data` into `Parameters_W.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is stored in a single string, you can do sth like this:

```py
with open("../QTLauncher/Parameters_W.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in data.splitlines()[0:52]
        f.write(line + "\n")
```

This splits your data at each newline. Then you iterate over the first 52 elements and write them into your file.